# How to set constrains for UIViewController (inside Storyboard)?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIviewController`. I don't know how to set contraints inside the StoryBoard. Can you help me?

My device is iPhone (from IPhone 6s Plus to belower IPhones).

[image: This is my design]

Comment: Do you make a research? And how to you want to set them - from code or in the StoryBoard?

Comment: i mean in Storyboard.

Comment: You can use this very good tutorial: [part1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) and [part2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints). Next time serach Google first!